# Having issues uploading file on s3 with a multipart/form-data through post request

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, lambda, postman, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to upload a file(multipart/form-data) to S3 bucket using node js lambda function from AWS API gateway post request through postman, but I am getting black image while passing event body in s3.putObject.

Below is Node js upload file handler.

```
exports.handler = function (event) {
var bodyBuffer = new Buffer(event['body-json']);
s3.putObject({
        ACL: 'public-read',
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME + '/' + folderName,
        Key: 'test.jpg',
        Body: bodyBuffer,
        ContentType: 'image/jpg'     },
    function(error, response) {
        console.log(arguments);
    });
}
```

Comment: How exactly are you handling a `multipart/form-data` post in such a way that something called `event['body-json']` (a string?) would contain the correct payload for your `bodyBuffer`?

Comment: I have created node js function for upload file on s3 and uploaded that zip to lambda and created one api post upload call from api gateway in aws.

Comment: I have used multipart/form-data in api and i am checking that api in postman. I have also checked console log output for event for body-json. It's something like this. Event: { 'body-json': 'LS0tLS0tV2ViS2l0Rm9ybUJvdW5kYXJ5SE9ZNkJLUDZZQlRPZ1lMdA0.....

Comment: And if you decode that base64, you find that it's still `multipart/form-data`... The content you showed decodes to `------WebKitFormBoundaryHOY6BKP6YBTOgYLt...`... it's definitely not a binary blob suitable for use in the object body buffer in `s3.putObject()`.

Comment: yes after decode, I got  `------WebKitFormBoundarye9Y8JZXDpei8ef4X
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="42345234242.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg ...... .. ..      ------WebKitFormBoundarye9Y8JZXDpei8ef4X--` Now how to set this to s3 put object body?

Comment: Please help me, Do I have to pass this decoded buffer directly to s3 bucket upload function body or something else?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Please help me, How to pass this decoded body `------WebKitFormBoundary` to `s3.putObject({Body:___________ })`? Do I have to parse or something other that?

Comment: I am getting this error while parsing from 'parse-multipart - npm'. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
at obj (/var/task/node_modules/parse-multipart/multipart.js:28:15)
at process (/var/task/node_modules/parse-multipart/multipart.js:37:14)`

Comment: Thanks, Michael. Got solutions. now it works the complete flow. it's awesome.

Comment: Please post an answer for the benefit of others.

Comment: yes sure, but still I have one problem. It's not working with multiple payloads like file and other fields too.

Comment: The form `POST` upload functionality built into S3 only supports one upload per HTTP request.